# MySql connector for .Net core truncates text to 255 characters

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core

Environment:

> Ubuntu 16.04, Asp.Net Core 1.1, MySql.Data 7.0.6-IR31, MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.6-IR31

The MySql database column in question is of data type "mediumtext." Here is my pseudo-code:

```
string qry = "UPDATE MyDb.MyTbl SET Comments = @p0 WHERE ID = @p1";
string comments = "a long long string";

using(var db = new AppDbContext()) {
   var numRecords = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(qry, comments, id);
   return numRecords;
}
```

When executed, the database table gets updated as expected. However, only the first 255 characters are being written into my "Comments" column.

Wondering if anyone can suggest a workaround.

Comment: check the field if its a varchar(255)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The data type is mediumtext which automatically implies it is a varchar of very long text. Besides, I can write the same query in MySQL workbench and the data is not truncated. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using entity framework, I switched to using plain old MySqlConnection/MySqlCommand classes. Inserts and updates seem to work now. I guess the bug is in MySql EF layer.